# Why is my variable undefined when I use "require"?

Tags: node.js, express, require

I have a simple function here to get the git ID (just for testing purposes). I don't understand how to set the variable when evaluating it from top to bottom. It is giving me undefined.

```js
var gitID;
require ('child_process').exec ('git rev-parse HEAD', function (err, stdout) {
  gitID = stdout;
});
console.log (gitID);
```

How do I set the variable at the top of my js file to be the git ID?

Comment: The issue isn't `require`. It's that this is an asynchronous operation with a callback and hence the line `gitID = stdout` runs much later than the line `console.log(gitID)`. So at the time you do `console.log(gitID)`, it is still undefined because the `git` process hasn't completed yet, so your callback with `gitID = stdout` inside of it hasn't run yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As has been said, it's because the call you're making is an async call using a callback and the `console.log(gitID)` is completing before the `exec` operation is able to complete and return the output, hence it is `undefined`.

A quick and simple way to solve this is to make use of the `promisify` util to wrap `exec` in:

```js
import { exec } from "child_process";
import { promisify } from "util";

const promisifiedExec = promisify(exec);

promisifiedExec("git rev-parse HEAD").then(res => console.log(res.stdout));
```

You can also look at constructing a function to return a promise, there's a lot of information about that in the linked question.